# ASP.NET MVC 5.1 EnumHelper.EnumDropDownListFor on enum with Flags attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I want to make a dropdownlist of an enum property on my ViewModel.

I've been searching for examples like [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/looking-at-asp-net-mvc-5-1-and-web-api-2-1-part-1-overview-and-enums) and [this](http://codewala.net/2014/04/17/exploring-enums-support-in-asp-net-mvc-5-1-part-2/#comment-15786) where they use enums for displaying a `select` and `radiobuttons` controls if a form.

I have an enum like this

```cs
class MyViewModel 
{
    public JobCategory JobCategory {get; set;}
}

[Flags]
public enum JobCategory
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Ninguna
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "N/A")]
    None = 0,

    /// <summary>
    /// Diseño Grafico
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Diseño Gráfico")]
    GraphicDesign = 1

    ...
}
```

And the form

```html
@model MyViewModel

<div class="col-xs-3">
        @(EnumHelper.IsValidForEnumHelper(Model.JobCategory.GetType())
        ? Html.EnumDropDownListFor(d => d.JobCategory, new { @class = "form-control" })
        : Html.EditorFor(d => d.JobCategory, new { @class = "form-control" }))
</div>
```

When I remove the `Flags` attribute the method `EnumHelper.IsValidForEnumHelper(Model.JobCategory.GetType())` returns `true` 
and displays a `select` otherwise returns `false` and the form displays a `textbox`.

Someone know how can I use this helper without removing the `Flags` attribute?

Comment: You cannot use this helper with flags. It's implementation actually checks for the `FlagsAttribute` and returns `false` if it is set. You would also have a problem with a drop down (I suppose multi-select), as the `None` value would always be selected.

Comment: Right, now I understand. Thanks.

Comment: It does seem like the `EnumDropDownListFor` does not support Flags enums. However, I think this is an excellent opportunity to create a custom helper. I think that a multi-select dropdown could handle this scenario quite nicely. How did you end up solving your problem?